# JQuery Datatables. How can I change the current page programmatically?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have pagination on my table. I want go back back to the first page whenever a function is called. How can I do that?

Comment: [API](http://www.datatables.net/api) -> `fnPageChange()`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

from the docs: http://datatables.net/ref#fnPageChange

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
  oTable.fnPageChange( 'first' );
} );
```

Answer (score 12):

```
var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
oTable.fnPageChange( 'first' );
```

OR

```
oTable.fnPageChange( 0 );
```

Comment: OP is trying to change page on function call, not on page load.

Answer (score 10):

This seems to work for me:

```
table.page(pageNumber).draw(false);
```

This works with pagination where `pageNumber` is the index of the page.

Comment: i have pagination on my table and i want to go back to the first page whenever a function is called and i use this line of code inside my function and works

Answer (score 8):

In the Datatables version 10 there is a page() function which is used to change the page.

For eg. `table.page('first');` will jump to first page

`table.page(pageNumber);` will jump to the corresponding page where `pageNumber` is indexed from 0.

Reference: http://datatables.net/reference/api/page()

Answer (score 0):

I have same problems. So this is my solution.

```js
var pageto = 5; /* insert page you want to open for the first time page load */
var t;
$(function () {

  t = $("#myTable").DataTable({
    "processing": true, 
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax":{
            url: url + 'datajson', 
            type: 'GET',
            "dataSrc": function (json) {
                totalRecords = json.recordsTotal;
                return json.data;
            }
        },
     "initComplete": function(settings, json){
            t.page(pageto).draw(false);
          }
  });

}
```

This will load datatables to exact page location