# How to pass page number , not page size while loading datatables

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I am able to load datatable by default with 2nd page by using the below script.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        dataTable =  jQuery('#tableid').DataTable( {
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        "displayStart": 10,
"ajax":{
  url :"load_browser_two_data.php,
  type: "POST" 
        }
})
});
```

By using the above script i am able to load 2nd page. But I need to pass page number instead of page size ("displayStart": 10). How can i achieve that one? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not call a function to calculate it correctly ? Would it make sense ?

Comment: as per my requirement passing page number is sufficient. could you please suggest how to do that?

Comment: Isn't that capability described here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16496054/jquery-datatables-how-can-i-change-the-current-page-programmatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just calculate the size out of your page number like so:

```
"displayStart": (pageNumber - 1) * 10
```

`pageNumber = 2` would produce 10. 3 => 20, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Although the question is answered, still my answer can be helpful to someone.
As there is a least chance of getting the page number to send and fetching data, one can also use the datatable's property of saving state of a table.

`$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        stateSave: true
    } );
});`
`
More description can be found here

[https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/state_save.html]

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate it as proposed but the problem is if you want to change the page size, you must change it in the DataTable setting AND in your formula.

To avoid that, you can also use the native `page()` function:
https://datatables.net/reference/api/page()#Example

Here is an example on how to use it:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "deferLoading": 0   /* This won't load initial data */

    // Your config comes here
    // ...
});

// Get the data for page 7 and draw the DataTable
table.page( 7 ).draw( false );


// For reference...

// Go to next page 
table.page( 'next' ).draw( 'page' );

// Go to previous page
table.page( 'previous' ).draw( 'page' );
```

You can also read more on [deferLoading](https://datatables.net/reference/option/deferLoading).