# AdminLTE. table page change 1 to other

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, adminlte, page-numbering

I have table used Bootstrap 3.

That is option

```
$('#DT_NoticeList').DataTable({
            "paging": true,
            "lengthChange": false,
            "searching": false,
            "ordering": false,
            "info": false,
            "autoWidth": false,
            "pageLength": 15
        });
```

If there are 10 page, how to change the page number 1 to other?

I want to change the page directly in Javascript or code side.

that is mean move page 1 to other in javascript or anyway

like this [ (1) 2 3 4 5 ] -> [ 1 2 (3) 4 5 ]

how to do?

Comment: What do you mean with "change the page number 1 to other" ?? Do you mean to change the text inside the turn-page button?

Comment: i want to change page number [ (1) 2 3 4 5 ] -> [ 1 2 (3) 4 5 ] in javascript or code side. move page 1 to other.

Comment: i find here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16496054/jquery-datatables-how-can-i-change-the-current-page-programmatically